# Calculation of space complexity of the recursive factorial function

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

How to calculate the space complexity of the following code as I am unable to do it.

```
somefunct(n)
{
  if(n==0)
     return 1;
  else
      return n * somefunct(n-1)
}
```

and how to calculate the time complexity of follwoing

```
int somefunct(int n)
{
  if(n<=2)
    return 1;
  else
    return (somefunct(floor(sqrt(x)))+x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think , space complexity of one function call should be simply multiplied by number of recursive calls to get actual space complexity of full algorithm ( program ) since space will be needed for all stacks.

Space complexity of one function call is one ( 1 ) because there is a single variable and there will be n+1 calls so space complexity will be n+1.

In terms of order , it can be called O(n).

Comment: `Space complexity of one function call is one ( 1 )` is true only if constant size parameters are used which is not entirely clear if true for this case. If the `n` is arbitrary precision number then it is not true, if it is constant size datatype then it is true. And at the same time the inside variables and heap usage must be also constant.  if the size depends on `n` (this is not the case unless compiler uses some temp variables on the heap instead of registers) then again your statement is not true. ... Just have to add this otherwise your answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks and yes, size of complex data type needs to be taken into account here. .For factorials, its generally understood that data type is plain integer.

Comment: For factorials are `bigints` quite common so the integer is not a good assumption unless specified ... how do you store `1000!` ... That i sthe main reason for my comment ...

Answer (score 0):

## General Space Complexity on Call Stack

If we're just looking at the space consumed on the stack, we make `n + 1` calls to your recursive method, therefore we use an asymptotic amount of memory equating to `O(n)`.

## Space Complexity of Bits (if you care about that)

As a quick recap, if we had some function which stored a *constant* amount of memory, then the space complexity would be `O(1)`. It's important to note that a constant amount of memory refers to some hard coded constant number that is independent of the algorithm.

So, for example, if we had some function which stored a number like `int myVar = n`, this *wouldn't* be considered constant memory, rather it would be `O(lg(n))` bits.

So with this in mind, let's take a look at your recursive algorithm. Each time your function is called, we push 2 things onto the call stack:

- A pointer to the function
- The argument

The function pointer is a constant amount of space, since the actual pointer never changes. The argument, however, is constantly changing relative to `n`. To be more specific, the argument has an upper bound of `O(lgn)` bits.

Now, we know that a single function call will consume `c * O(lgn)` bits. Since we need to call this `n + 1` times, we observe:

```
c * O(lgn) + c * O(lg(n-1)) + c * O(lg(n-2)) + ... + c * O(1)
```

Therefore, we can conclude that the space complexity is `O(nlg(n))` bits.

## Conclusion

This function consumes `O(n)` space, or `O(nlgn)` bits of space.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Care to expound on that for the sake of my answer improving/me learning? I fail to see immediately how my assertion was wrong - if the function uses `m` amounts of memory and it is called `n` times, why isn't the amount of memory consumed `m * n`?

Comment: @GauravSehgal Ah I meant *addition* here, still early in the morning for me :)

Comment: Let's start with the basics: "The only time we utilize memory is when we return" - nope, first you need space for the function argument(s).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Was my observation on the bits relevant here? I realized afterwards that we might not care for calculating the bits since we're really just allocating memory on the call stack. Does this make my bit observation moot in this context?

Comment: the (call) stack is also space.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Right, I wasn't suggesting it wasn't. I was asking if discussing the bits in respect to the recursive calls relevant because I imagine we're pushing a reference to function with the parameters onto the call stack, not necessarily storing the bits anywhere. Could you explain further?

Comment: "we're pushing a reference to function with the parameters onto the call stack, not necessarily storing the bits anywhere" - that's a contradiction: that's one way to store bits. make up your mind.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath A reference to a function would be a constant amount of bits since it'd just be a pointer, no? Or is that wrong? No need to be curt - just trying to learn

Answer (score 0):

Space Complexity: O(n) call stack
Time Complexity: O(sqrt(n)) because every time recursive call reduced to sqrt(n).